# Send an email to verify the account then update to the new email

Tags: swift, firebase, email, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase as a backend service for authentication and storing data. 
In our application, we need to give the user ability to change the email. 
When a user creates an account we are sending him verification email using Firebase method

```
 Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: user.email, password: password) { (_, error) in
       if error != nil {
       // Error handling
       Utilities.HUDstopLoading()
        Utilities.alertWhileCreateingNewAccount(self.viewController, errorMessage: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Something wrong happend")
       } else {
       // Account created
       }
```

There is nothing wrong with it.

**The problem occurs when user wants to change email**
Because when updating an email it automatically updates in Firebase Authentication. 
Now, when the user makes a typo in the email then verification email is sent to the wrong address but despite this email is updated in Firebase Authentication.

I am using this function for updating an email:

```
      currentUser.updateEmail(to: newEmail) { (error) in
          if let error = error 
          // Error happend while updating email
          print("Error happend while updating email \(error)")
         Utilities.alertWhileCreateingNewAccount(self.viewController, errorMessage: error.localizedDescription )} 
   else {                        
        self.sendEmailVerification()
        currentUser.reload(completion: nil)                        
        Utilities.successHUD(in: self.viewController.view)
         self.viewController.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }

          }
```

For Android, there is a method called

```
verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(String newEmail)
```

and it works perfectly. It sends user verification to new email and waits until the user verifies an email, if not the previous email remains. 
In documentation for iOS, I found the same function but... it does not exist in FirebaseAuth...

[image]

Is there any way how can I solve this problem by updating an email for the iOS app? It would be very strange if Firebase allows updating email without verifying...

Comment: *firebaser here* "It would be very strange if Firebase allows updating email without verifying..." That is precisely what it does, though I agree is not ideal for your usage. At the moment you'll have to implement the alternate flow yourself. But it might be good to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).